# Draw a rectangle which is draggable

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, ios4

If I draw a rectangle on a frame and then I want to drag this rectangle to different positions on this frame. How could I do this? Please add comments if my description is unclear. It might be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UIView` with any background image and move it on a window by setting its frame as `yourView.center = CGPointMake(x,y);`

You can detect the point of touch using any/all of `touchesBegan` , `touchesMoved` or `touchesEnded` methods as follows :

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint =[touch locationInView:self.view];//point of touch
}
```

These methods are to be declared in a `UIViewController`. As sample code, you can refer to my [github](https://github.com/aakash272/dragDrop) project in which I drag an item from one `UITableView` to another `UITableView` which I've accomplished using `UIView`s.